# Is a Firebase (JSON) database on Kivy possible?

Tags: python, firebase, kivy

#### Summary:

I'm using `python-firebase` to work with an online database. My app integrated flawlessly with a Firebase database on Pycharm, but when I opened the app on my phone, it crashed.

#### Error:

The logcat error was: `ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing`

#### Attempted:

I used both `requirements = firebase` (build failed) and `requirements = python-firebase` (build successful but crashed on opening, which is where the logcat error came from).

I know it's a problem with Firebase because when I removed `from firebase import firebase` and recompiled the app, it worked.

#### Any recommendation?

If this specific package of Firebase doesn't work with Kivy, is there a Kivy package/library that works with online JSON databases?

#### Sample of python-firebase:

```
from firebase import firebase

fb = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://your_storage.firebaseio.com', None)
result = fb.get('/users', '1')
print result

{'1': 'John Doe'}
```

Comment: Did you include the libraries in the build.spec?

Comment: @el3ien Yes, sorry I'll add that part! I used both `requirements = firebase` and `requirements = python-firebase`. Would this be the correct requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to the creator of the package, and he notified me that they'll look into the issue.

In the meantime, I used `requests` to access Firebase. I created a tutorial for the the community. Here is the link to the GitHub page: https://github.com/Petar-Luketina/Firebase-Sample . If the code is unclear, there's a link to my YouTube tutorial in the `README.md`.